# Header and iframe not optimized for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a website that needs mobile optimization. https://springtribe.de/
I got stuck with the following:

1. My header is too small on mobile.
   Ideally, the header should look like this:

[image: in the ideal world]

But in reality, the icons and text on the header are too small to read on mobile:

[image: stuff too small on the mobile header]

2. iFrame doesn't get optimized for mobile.

My current mobile version does display the iframe, but just like the header the content displays very tiny stuff to read.

Ideally, the iframe should be responsive to the tiny mobile screen like this:
[image: in the ideal world]

However, in the reality, the iframe keeps the desktop display even on the mobile screen.

[image]

I believe I messed up my CSS or Html, so I'd appreciate it if any of you could advise me on this. For your reference all the relevant source codes are here:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #c6c1c1;
  background-color: white;
}

header .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.875rem;
}

header .site-logo {
  flex: 1;
  width: 60%
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header>
  <div class="content" style="height: 45px;">
    <a href="index.html" class="site-logo"><img src="./resources/images/cropped_springtribelogo_notagline.png" style="height:60px;"></a>
    <nav class="desktop">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="impressumen.html">Imprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="landingde.html">DE</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en"><img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram (1.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de"><img class="Linkedin" src="./resources/images/Linkedin_saturated_4.png" style="width: 20px; color: #de6cb6; margin-left: 8px;"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="mobile">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="impressumen.html"><img src="./resources/images/imp_new.png" style="width: 20px;"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="landingde.html">DE</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/springtribe.de/?hl=en"><img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram (1.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/florian-zejewski-03653b164/?originalSubdomain=de"><img class="Linkedin" src="./resources/images/Linkedin_saturated_4.png" style="width: 20px; color: #de6cb6; margin-left: 8px;"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Filters Section -->
<div id="filters-section">
  <div class="content center">
    <h2>Your adventure starts here.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="podcast">
    <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://anchor.fm/springtribe" width="1500" height="600"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to use the `<meta name="viewport">` tag in the `<head>` section of your HTML document. Here's an example.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If this helps, please mark it as "Correct!"

Comment: Thank you for the response! I already did the viewport thing, but a couple of items still display in the desktop mode. For example, iFrame still displays the tiny text on mobile after I applied the viewport tag.

Comment: @morry239 If the iframe still displays tiny text, and it's the correct size of the page, then the iframe's page is the problem. There's no way to scale the inside of an iframe when it's cross-origin without the CSS `transform` property, or accessing the iframe directly with a GET request.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the transform property. I have been trying to adjust it but still my iframe stays the mobile size when the screen is mobile. Could you kindly provide the example of the GET request for me?

Comment: @morry239 If you have access to PHP, a GET request can be seen in PHP code by using `$_GET`. I would suggest learning PHP if you're going down this route. In simple code, this is what you'd want on the iframe: `if(isset($_GET["mobile"])) { echo "You're on <b>mobile</b>."; } else {echo "You're on <b>desktop</b>."; }` Access the frame page with SRC containing `?mobile` if you're on mobile, and nothing if you're on desktop. PHP is more simple as a language if you know what you're doing.